# Sharing data between pages

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I have a page inside an App that shows a list of items. When the user selects an item the App navigates to a second page containing the details of the selected item. A typical scenario I think.

I read tons of articles on the internet but I still would like to hear the opinion of experts on the subject.

I already found two alternatives that appear to be the best:

**Messaging** Page1 navigates to Page2 and ViewModel2 sends a message back to ViewModel1 asking for the selected item. The message would contain a callback that acts as a setter.

**Shared Service** a service exists that exposes all the data that should be shared between the two ViewModels. In this case it would be:

```
interface IAppService
{
    object SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

If the two VMs get this service injected in the constructor we are done.

So, in a nutshell, what's the recommended way of sharing data between the ViewModels of two different pages?

Comment: Hello, did you managed to solve the problem ?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas well I'm using different solutions everytime depending on the situation. I'd say there isn't any best choice. Both the suggestions I provided myself work well anyway.